# Loading shiny module only when menu items is clicked

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

## Background

Within a modular<sup>1</sup> Shiny application, I would like to load module only when menu item on [shinydashboard](/questions/tagged/shinydashboard) is clicked. If the menu item is not accessed I wouldn't like to load the module.

## Basic application

### `app.R`

```
# Libs
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Source module
source("sample_module.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenuOutput("menu")),
    dashboardBody(tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "tab_one", h1("Tab One")),
        tabItem(tabName = "tab_two", sampleModuleUI("sampleModule"))
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    callModule(sampleModuleServer, "sampleModule")

    output$menu <- renderMenu({
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem(
                "Menu item 1",
                icon = icon("calendar"),
                tabName = "tab_one"
            ),
            menuItem(
                "Menu item 2",
                icon = icon("globe"),
                tabName = "tab_two"
            )
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### `sample_module.R`

```
sampleModuleServer <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        plot(mtcars)
    })
}

sampleModuleUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)

    plotOutput(ns("plot1"))

}
```

## Desired implementation

The desired implementation would load `sample_module` only when the relevant menu item is clicked. On the lines of <sup>2</sup>:

Don't call callModule from inside observeEvent; keep it at the top level. Take the reactive expression that's returned, and use eventReactive to wrap it in the button click. And use the eventReactive from your outputs, etc.

> ```
> x <- callModule(...)
> y <- eventReactive(input$go, x())
> output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(y())
> ```

## Attempt

### `app.R` *(modified)*

```
# Libs
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Source module
source("sample_module.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenuOutput("menu")),
    dashboardBody(tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = "tab_one", h1("Tab One")),
        tabItem(tabName = "tab_two", sampleModuleUI("sampleModule"))
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    eventReactive(eventExpr = input$tab_two,
                  valueExpr = callModule(sampleModuleServer, "sampleModule")
    )

    output$menu <- renderMenu({
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem(
                "Menu item 1",
                icon = icon("calendar"),
                tabName = "tab_one"
            ),
            menuItem(
                "Menu item 2",
                icon = icon("globe"),
                tabName = "tab_two"
            )
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Problem

Application runs but the module does not load. Questions:

- How to correctly call `eventReactive` on dashboard menu item? The `tab_item` does not seem to have `id` parameter is `tabName` equivalent in that context?
- The linked discussion refers to refreshing one table. I'm trying to figure out example that will work with modules containing numerous interface element and elaborate server calls.

Clicking on *Menu item 2* should display the content from the **`sample_module.R`** file.

[image: application layout]

---

<sup>1</sup> [*Modularizing Shiny app code*](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

<sup>2</sup> [*Google groups: activate module with actionButton*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/8ajkjj9g0eI)

---

## Update

I've tried explicitly forcing module into application environment load using the following syntax:

```
eventReactive(eventExpr = input$tab_two,
              valueExpr = callModule(sampleModuleServer, "sampleModule"),
              domain = MainAppDomain
)
```

where

```
MainAppDomain <- getDefaultReactiveDomain()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit: Dropping Joe Cheng's top level statement:

```
# Libs
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Source module
source("sample_module.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenuOutput("menu")),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab_one", h1("Tab One")),
    tabItem(tabName = "tab_two", sampleModuleUI("sampleModule"))
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$tabs,{
    if(input$tabs=="tab_two"){
      callModule(sampleModuleServer, "sampleModule")
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem(
                  "Menu item 1",
                  icon = icon("calendar"),
                  tabName = "tab_one"
                ),
                menuItem(
                  "Menu item 2",
                  icon = icon("globe"),
                  tabName = "tab_two"
                )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Furthermore, your `sidebarMenu` needs an id to access the selected tabs; please see the shinydashboard [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/behavior.html).

---

**Edit:** if we want to run `callModule` only *once* on the first click (just like @UgurDar), we can introduce a blocking variable:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Source module
source("sample_module.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenuOutput("menu")),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab_one", h1("Tab One")),
    tabItem(tabName = "tab_two", sampleModuleUI("sampleModule"))
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(tab_two_loaded = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$tabs,{
    if(!(rv$tab_two_loaded) && input$tabs=="tab_two"){
      callModule(sampleModuleServer, "sampleModule")
      rv$tab_two_loaded <- TRUE
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem(
                  "Menu item 1",
                  icon = icon("calendar"),
                  tabName = "tab_one"
                ),
                menuItem(
                  "Menu item 2",
                  icon = icon("globe"),
                  tabName = "tab_two"
                )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for showing the interest. Not sure if this does the job. To test, Within `sampleModuleServer ` I've included `stop("Module loaded, crashing...")`. Now the app crashes on start (it does not launch). Whereas to my mind, *it shouldn't* it should only crash if I trigger the event calling this module (clicking on the link). Is that a sensible assumption?

Comment: Well, then it seems we need to join the dark side and use observeEvent anyway. - please check my edit.

Comment: Second Edit is working but if you have reactive inputs in module you need to identify another flag for it, and it can be difficult if you have too many tabs and reactive values. Also if you re-initialize the tab, this means all the values and reactives are being duplicated, and over time can cause memory leaks. Having the UI portion of the tabs initialize once but the server initialize many times can also cause bugs that are difficult to notice.

Comment: @UgurDar the first option also works. It is just a matter of what you are trying to achive. I'm not sure I follow the rest of your explanations. It might be better to wrap up your specific use case in a reproducible example and post it along side a separate question.